# RSpec: invalid model with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, searchkick

I'm not very sure I'm doing it right, but I have two models: `House` that `has_one Address`.

The `Address` model has:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
  belongs_to :house
end
```

I'm trying to test my `house_controller` with RSpec like this

```
RSpec.describe HousesController do
 context 'GET #index' do
 before { get :index }
 it     { is_expected.to render_template('index') }

 it 'assigns @houses' do
  h = create(:house)
  expect(assigns(:houses).results).to eq([h])
end
...
```

Nevertheless I always get a result which is not the one I expect.
The code of my controller is the following:

```
def index
 if params[:term].present?
  @houses = House.search(params[:term])
 else
  @houses = House.search('*')
 end
end
```

I'm not sure I understand it, but could it be that since I'm using `FactoryBot`, it is creating lots of houses, and then when getting in the `index` method, there's a bunch of houses there and not only and precisely `h`?

This is my failure:

```
Failures:

  1) HousesController GET #index assigns @houses
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:houses).results).to eq([h])

       expected: [#<House id: 763, rent: 1173, deposit: 739, description: "Rerum cado curso curo alias.", preferred_ge...2018-11-26 21:40:43", available_at: "2018-12-17", user_id: 15945, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>]
            got: [#<House id: 215, rent: 0.839e3, deposit: 0.797e3, description: "Rerum aeneus taceo crepusculum aestu...2018-11-26 21:17:53", available_at: "2018-12-17", user_id: 15776, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>]

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
       -[#<House id: 763, rent: 1173, deposit: 739, description: "Rerum cado curso curo alias.", preferred_gender: 0, created_at: "2018-11-26 21:40:43", updated_at: "2018-11-26 21:40:43", available_at: "2018-12-17", user_id: 15945, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>]
       +[#<House id: 215, rent: 0.839e3, deposit: 0.797e3, description: "Rerum aeneus taceo crepusculum aestus.", preferred_gender: 0, created_at: "2018-11-25 12:50:11", updated_at: "2018-11-25 12:50:11", available_at: "2018-12-16", user_id: 8065, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>,
       + #<House id: 235, rent: 0.519e3, deposit: 0.642e3, description: "Cicuta totidem arbustum arcesso fugit tego.", preferred_gender: 0, created_at: "2018-11-25 12:54:28", updated_at: "2018-11-25 12:54:28", available_at: "2018-12-16", user_id: 8085, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>,
       + #<House id: 648, rent: 0.668e3, deposit: 0.1104e4, description: "Corporis tametsi demens.", preferred_gender: 0, created_at: "2018-11-26 21:17:43", updated_at: "2018-11-26 21:17:43", available_at: "2018-12-17", user_id: 15775, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>,
       + #<House id: 649, rent: 0.799e3, deposit: 0.611e3, description: "Ut ancilla tredecim.", preferred_gender: 0, created_at: "2018-11-26 21:17:53", updated_at: "2018-11-26 21:17:53", available_at: "2018-12-17", user_id: 15776, lease_length: nil, built_in: nil>]

     # ./spec/controllers/houses_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm starting with RSpec now and it's really taking me effort and hours to try to grab the grasp of it, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you expect it to have one result or many?  yes, it looks like you're creating more house's somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searchkick [docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#rspec) about disabling indexing for tests with RSpec.

You don't want to be updating your objects in Elasticsearch always while running tests. You want to do it only when you'll be explicitly testing your search functionality (or indexing/deleting from index). To do so, you will have to disable searchkick callbacks, define a custom tag for your tests and enable indexing only for these tests. You may have to handle cleaning your index after a test/groups of tests as well.

@vich's point is also important, you currently create your object too late, after the request.

I would change your setup to:

```
context 'GET #index', :search do
  let!(:house) { create(:house) }
  before { get :index }

  it 'assigns @houses' do
    expect(assigns(:houses).results).to eq([house])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated response! unfortunately it doesn't seem to be any house in the `House` table

Comment: They're not in the table, your database is being cleared properly between tests. Each time you're creating a house, it is being indexed in your Elasticsearch, which is not being cleared. If you follow the instructions from the docs I've linked, you will be able to configure that properly.

Comment: indeed this was the solution, thanks a lot! it is sometimes difficult for me as a newbie to know what was exactly what fixed it, and why (there's not a lot explanation in the searchkick github website)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your `house` in the before block:

```
context 'GET #index' do
  before do
    let!(:house) { create(:house) }
    get :index
  end

  it { is_expected.to render_template('index') }

  it 'assigns @houses' do
    expect(assigns(:houses).results).to eq([house])
  end
end
```

A couple of things to note:

1. As opposed to `let`, `let!` is immediately invoked (thus creating your record before the index action is hit)
2. Add a breakpoint (IDE) or use a debugger (byebug, pry, etc.) and put it before the `get :index` call to see what (if any) houses already exist.

Comment: I've tried the `byebug` but `House.all` shows an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `House.count` shows 0